# HTML: Trying to remove element from embedded Google Calendar

Tags: html, css, embed

I embedded a google calendar into my html using something like this:

```
<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=blahblahblahblahblah" style="border: 0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

I am trying to remove that "+Google Calendar" button on the calendar page. I can inspect the element and figure out what it is I need to change:

[image: calendarInspect]

However, I do not understand what to change to take it out. I tried adding this to the style.css page:

```
div.subscribe-image{
    display: none;
}
```

that did not work. Let me know if you know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change the inline style when inspecting the element.

For example: You are highlighting the element, then you can see it says this.

```
style="display: inline-block"
```

Try changing that inline style while inspecting the element to this.

```
style="display: none"
```

My thought is that you are selecting something that doesn't yet exist when the css style is looking for it. To your document, all it sees is the iFrame, not the entire google code that it pulls in, you cant access code within an iFrame. Know what I'm saying?

To my knowledge. I maybe wrong, and there maybe a solution. Try this and then we can look deeper for solutions.

Comment: yes, if i change it to style="display: none" then it is gone. But it will still be there for other people. I guess this iFrame thing will not let us edit those elements. So I am not sure of a way around this.

Comment: Hey, what is your intention of removing it, is it because the branding is annoying? Is there a way you could send me a link to view this so I can inspect myself, to mess around with it?

Comment: it's for a project where I am putting this touchscreen outside of my professor's office which displays the professor's google calendar in kiosk mode. We do not want someone clicking on that Google Calendar button and going elsewhere on the screen.

Comment: Oh, actually I have a thought. What if you take the page source, copy the iframe code into your document, then apply the style. Instead of having the iframe, copy the code that it imports, then try to style it. Also, people speack of this 'same origin policy rules'. Please be careful, specially with companies like google. I am not sure what the rules say, but I think it is becasue of advertisement reasons, and branding reasons on behalf of google services. I have a website that uses google forms, and it has the branding, but give this a try. No reason why it shouldnt work.

Comment: Ok, so should I literally copy all of the html from top to bottom?

Comment: Well, this is the only way I can think of doing this. Check this out. First copy the src="###" link from the iframe, then paste that into the browser, then right click and view source. Copy all of that, then save that code as your own html file. Then pull in the iframe again, but this time point it to your local html file, then try to change the style, i think that should work! I will be amazed, I have never tried this, just theoretical. 25% experimental.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136010/discussion-between-teamamplified-and-slinkymation).

Answer (score 1):

It's an `<iframe>`. That's a different document. You have no access to it, unless it allows you access. To understand the principle, it's pretty much like you would try to change something in another browser tab, from your tab.

The only option is to remove the `<iframe>`. You can't traverse its `DOM` if it doesn't allow you to.

What you are attempting is governed by [`same origin policy`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) rules. If the `<iframe>` provider allows it, you need to set a **Cookie to header** [`CSRF token`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Cookie-to-Header_Token).

Comment: so is there a way that I can still embed the calendar without using iframe so that I can remove that button?

Comment: You should look in the iframe provider's docs, if they provide such an option. Most likely, they'll require money.

Comment: @SlinkyMation, hypothetically speaking, you have an option. You could cover the portion of the `<iframe>` that renders the button with an element from your page. However, it's not easy to do cross-browser cross-device. You want to make *creative use of web mechanics* to disable users' ability to scroll the `<iframe>` into a position where the button would become visible. Needless to say, I'm pretty sure if the `<iframe>` provider finds out about it, he's not gonna like it. They must have had a reason to put that button there. What do you think?

Comment: It's only going to be on a local web server is that not legal?

Comment: 1. I don't know. 2. I don't want to know. 3. That's not a programming question. 4. If you're worried about the legal part, I am absolutely sure it is covered in *T&C* of the iframe provider and I'm also pretty sure you had to check a box saying you read/agree with them. || You can totally disregard my previous remark and try to do it. Provide a [mcve] and I'll even help you do it. As in: this is tricky to do. I need to see where it's implemented to come up with something that would work.